# Can I exclude .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG from file-name-history?

Tags: magit, git, history, history-variables, filenames

Is there a way to exclude `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` files from `file-name-history`? Now that I'm authoring commits with Magit, those commit message files are often the most recent entries in `file-name-history`, which is annoying since they're never what I'm looking for when scrolling through history entries.

Comment: Are you sure you mean `file-name-history` and not `recentf-list`? If it is the latter, then you can use `recentf-exclude`. On the other hand `git-commit.el` already includes `(eval-after-load 'recentf '(add-to-list 'recentf-exclude git-commit-filename-regexp))`, so you shouldn't have to.

Comment: Only files that you actually select when using `find-file` and such should be added to `file-name-history` (I think). Do you do that? Why?

Comment: @tarsius I haven't used `find-file` on a `COMMIT_EDITMSG` file, but when I use `find-file` and hit `M-p` (previous-history-element), there's usually a `COMMIT_EDITMSG` in there. To confirm, I first deleted it from file-name-history, inspecting the variable to ensure it was gone. Then I used Magit to author a commit, and inspecting file-name-history again showed it back in there.

Comment: Hm, maybe my assumptions about when something gets added to `file-name-history` are wrong.

Comment: `server-visit-files` adds the file to `file-name-history`. I don't see any way to prevent that short of advising that function.

Comment: @tarsius To be fair, it's not a huge deal most of the time. It's only when I'm editing the same files frequently (like editing init.el as I learn emacs) that I rely on `M-p`. Aside from that, I generally use `C-r` instead. So just a minor annoyance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files (`COMMIT_EDITMSG`, `git-rebase-todo` and others) are added to `file-name-history` by `server-visit-files`. It is possible to undo that by advising that function, and I have implemented that.

But I am unsure whether that advise should also remove entries for these files that already existed prior to that function being called. I think so because those entries are very likely there from before this advice was added. On the other hand this might surprise users who, for whatever reason, edit these files by manually opening them. I'll decide at a later time.